# enums setter and getter

Tags: c#, enums, getter-setter

I could have used the following construct today (which does not compile)

```
public enum RecordedOrPlayed
{
    None {get,private set}
    Recorded,
    Played
}
enum SoundStatus = SoundStatus.None
```

Would this be useful?

EDIT - in response to remarks

Explanation:

I wanted a way of having a first-time value which cannot be used. II had a Sound class which when created had done nothing. Sound did different things depending on its status. The class may be used by other programmers. Once it has recorded or played it can never return to None. I did not want intellisense to be prompting None when it is not an option. As of C#7 we can do it for properties

```
public string str {get; private set;} = "First time only";
```

I realise it could be done with something like...

```
    public RecordedOrPlayed recordedOrPlayed
    {
        get { return _recordedOrPlayed; }
        set
        {
            if (value == RecordedOrPlayed.None)
                throw new ArgumentException("yada yada");
            _recordedOrPlayed = value;
        }
    }
```

...but it is ugly, hard to grasp at a glance, adds another variable and requires 10 lines of code to replace the setter.

Comment: What are you asking? `enum` values are constants. Are you saying it would be useful to be able to change the underlying integer value of a particular enumeration constant? I doubt you'll find much consensus for that. If you need something like that, I'd create a class that contains `int` properties `None`, `Recorded`, `Played`, etc.

Comment: Your code does not compile because the syntax and usage is clearly wrong (as you noted). Your question is also not clear...

Comment: @BobKaufman  You are both right. I realise there are multiple ways of doing the same thing but it doesn't solve the intellisense problem. I could have used a bool? or int?, a struct with accessor or some other devious code that is hard to understand at first glance. See above

Comment: @svek See above, can only notify one person per comment

Comment: @Paulustrious - please visit our help pages. In your comment, delimit keywords with a backtick (unshifted tilde "~" on an American QWERTY keyboard). "bool? or int?" is ambiguous. `bool`? and `bool?` mean different things. The former is ending a question and the latter is shorthand for `Nullable<bool>`

Answer (score 2):

As of 20 minutes there are 8 downvotes so I think the question is answered not by me but by popular opinion. This will probably not be incorporated in C#8

Also this question and another has caused me to be banned from asking further questions. I realise it is a jury of my peers, but I did not think the question so heinous that it warrants that punishment

Answer (score 0):

> Enums are simply constant integer values with a label...

So

```
public enum RecordedOrPlayed
{
    None,
    Recorded,
    Played
}
```

Would end up compiling to

```
public const int RecordedOrPlayed_None = 0;
public const int RecordedOrPlayed_Recorded = 1;
public const int RecordedOrPlayed_Played = 2;
```

What you are trying to achieve with your use, will never compile to the kind of behavior you are talking about with the getter and setters, as it's not what enums are designed for at all.

*This critical misunderstanding is where all your down votes are coming from.*

> What you are proposing is hide an `enum` from IntelliSense, which is the equivalent of saying, hide a `public const`... You can see why people aren't understanding your question.

Comment: I understand, but it could be done in various ways and be valid syntax.

Comment: Timedout. @Svec I understand, but it could be done in various ways and be valid syntax such as `{ [EnumNoSet] None, [EnumSet (ie default)] Recorded, Played}` The compiler can do anything it wants. Look at the way it plays round with return values when you have `Task<string> RecordAsync().....return "Ignore"`; BTW, I worded the question so briefly so as not push my 'why' and let others give their 'why' and 'why-not'. It was a mistake. And to BobK I will read the help.

Comment: @Paulustrious then why wouldn't you use a Factory pattern that returns Enums? It seems to do what you're asking.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Another syntax error which could have been used is `public const int RecordedOrPlayed_None =>1;`. Something that would compile is if the compiler had generated `public static int RecordedOrPlayed_None  => 0;` It's not important as there are many workarounds. Thank you for your contributions. Much appreciated